# Damaged exterior moisture barrier behind brick veneer

Tags: brick

I saw a similar question here but it was never really answered. I live in Houston, in a brick veneer house that is about 35 years old.  I have a thin cardboard applied to the studs as a moisture barrier behind the brick veneer. Termites and moisture have damaged one wall and destroyed the barrier.

The termites and moisture have been dealt with, and now I have to put this wall back together. I understand the need for the moisture barrier as brick is porous but I really don't want to have to remove the brick to do it. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Is there an air gap behind the brick veneer?

Comment: Yes, there is a gap of about 2".

Comment: Also, if it matters, this wall is in a bathroom with the tub next to it.

Comment: Not an expert on the subject matter, but I would probably remove and fiberglass batt insulation and spray foam the exterior wall cavity.

Comment: @DavidB -- what is the tub surround made of?

Comment: Sheetrock and insulation have been removed.  Tub surround WAS tile. Wall is down to bare studs, what's left of the cardboard sheathing and the exterior brick veneer.

Comment: I think I've come up with a solution.  Since the sheathing is still there, just not intact, thanks to the termites, I'm thinking I could use Tyvek on the interior stud bays.  Staple it to the studs, keeping the stud cavity depth and then reinsulate and drywall.  Thoughts?